# Call search API after UITextField changed, Moya

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am doing search feature, I want to call api after my search textField changed. I am using Moya, how can I do that?
Is there anyone have idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Moya, it will return an Object Cancellable when you call a request.
You just need to save that object, and then when you make another request, you cancel the previous request.

Example:

```
var previousRequest: Cancellable?

func search(text: String) {
    previousRequest?.cancel()
    //make new request...
}
```